# How can I browse my hard disk drive?

Tags: hard-drive, files

I have a hdd with 3 partitions and I would like to browse for my files but I can only use the Desktop and thats about all. I am not experienced with ubuntu, but I am sick and tired of Windows.

I've read about the Command Line and how it works but it bugs me that i can't really find my partitions. Is there an explorer-like application that i can use so i can safely browse the content of my hard disk drive?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

This is `nautilus` (aka Files). It is the default file browser for Ubuntu (like Windows Explorer on Windows):
[image]
<sub>Note: It might look different on your machine because I am using different themes (United-Ubuntu for GTK+ and Paper for icons) than the default Ambiance theme.</sub>

To get to Files just type "Files" in the dash. You can go to the dash by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> (known as the Windows key on Windows). The dash is like the Start Menu on Windows.

Click on "Other Locations" on the left bar to get to this window:
[image]

Here you can find all of your drives, partitions and remote drives listed. Click on one to browse it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert as well, but i managed to find them:

In Ubuntu, the Windows Explorer-like archive viewer is nautilus, you can open it from commandline ([Ctrl] [Alt] [T]), typing "nautilus", or by browsing a icon, probably named "Files" (mine is in native language) after hitting the "Win" key or Unity icon.

-> After you open it, try to go "File System"/"Computer" in the side bar, you will find several folders like "dev", "bin", "usr", "lib".

-> Open the "media" one.

-> Open the folder that has your username

-> It should list the other drives/partitions

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you have graphical user interface (GUI), use `nautilus`.

If you prefer command line interface (CLI), use [`Midnight-commander`](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/install-midnight-commander-mc-473-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

Although it's an old post, i happened to ask the same question and stumbled upon this post.
In case there is a need for a graphical representation of a disk drive's contents (like treemap for ex), use Baobab https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Baobab
[image]